# Stripping Commission Junction Links

Tags: affiliate, commission-junction

A typical Commission Junction product link looks like this:

> `http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-6751881-10368321?url=http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CJRedirect?linktype=product&id=202941995&cjsku=202941995`

This will redirect to the following URL:

> `http://www.homedepot.com/p/t/202941995?productId=202941995&storeId=10051&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&PID=6741882&cm_mmc=CJ-_-6751882-_-10368321&AID=10368321&cj=true`

The question: can I post the homedepot.com links directly and still get the commission?

Put it other way: Will I get the commission (for a qualified sale) by simply appending my CJ tracker info to a homedepot.com product URL?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, yes. So long as your links to the advertiser website are redirected through a CJ redirect domain (like androzers.net in your example) CJ will cookie the user for the attribution window and you will earn a commission on the sale.

Note that your example has an error that could break your links. The destination URL (URL of the product page) is supposed to be [url-encoded](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) so the correct syntax for your link would be:

```
http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-6751881-10368321?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.com%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fstores%2Fservlet%2FCJRedirect%3Flinktype%3Dproduct%26id%3D202941995&cjsku=202941995
```

Also, the `&cjsku=` parameter is not necessary and is only there to provide analytics to advertisers. No harm in including that, but also no harm in ignoring it either.

For reference, check out my more detailed answer here: [Commission Junction Direct Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452943/commission-junction-direct-links/11385614#11385614)

Finally, an alternative that you might find easier is to download Home Depot's product catalog, which is a list of all products they sell along with the links already prepared for you with your publisher PID.

[image]

Comment: Where are the cookies located? can you explain how do the CJ cookies works and how do you identify them, and identify that they contain your PID? are they for example, sent from the advertiser domain, or the andoezrs.com domain? and how do they come in action when a sale is made?